# Array item toggling simplification in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

is it possible to simplify the following code further, or is this the cleanest way possible? What I'm trying to do is, if the action.payload is not included in roles array, push it into it, if it is there remove it. I don't want to use lodash for this.

```
const idx = state.rolesFilter.findIndex(
  role => role === action.payload,
);
if (idx === -1) {
  nextState.roles.push(action.payload);
} else {
  nextState.roles = state.roles.filter(role => role !== action.payload);
}
```

Comment: Why do you mutate your array when adding but avoid mutation when removing?

Comment: So you have `state.rolesFilter`, `state.roles`, `nextState.roles`... How do all these arrays relate? The description seems to about a different situation (same array) than your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Set`

```
const set = new Set(state.roles);
const action = set.has(action.payload) ? 'delete' : 'add';
set[action](action.payload);
nextState.roles = [...set];
```

If you plan on using "toggle" a lot you may create a function

```
function toggle(array, item) {
    const set = new Set(array);
    const action = set.has(item) ? 'delete' : 'add';
    set[action](item);
    return [...set];
}
```